# Backbone Views / Jasmine / Requirejs - Cannot read property replace of undefined

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, jasmine

Using Jasmine, I have already written tests for my models and controllers and all have passed.  However, I am running into a lot of problems if I test my views.

1. IF I remove `views/hf_appView` from the define function in `base.js`, the PostViewSpec test will pass.  This is just a very simple and contrived example, but it illustrates an error I keep getting (in the developer tools console of my browser) when trying to test other views as well.
2. See the second example below in which I can't get to work at all. I did this to see if a different view module would work given there might be something wrong with the base module, but no luck.
3. Even in the passing collection spec, I then added a reference to `views/hf_postView` in the define function just to see what happens to the test and then all of a sudden I get the same error as #1 & 2 noted below.

Based on the errors below, one theory I have is that: **Perhaps the #listTpl that is attached to the view is not passed through because the DOM isn't ready as the view gets parsed?  If so, how can I fix this?**

Again, the models and controllers pass, but once I start including the view modules I am having a lot trouble. The error is:

**Error in Chrome**

```
Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

**Error in Safari**

```
[Warning] Invalid CSS property declaration at: * (jasmine.css, line 16)
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'n.replace')
    template (underscore-min.js, line 5)
    (anonymous function) (hf_postView.js, line 12)
    execCb (require.js, line 1658)
    check (require.js, line 874)
    (anonymous function) (require.js, line 624)
    each (require.js, line 57)
    breakCycle (require.js, line 613)
    (anonymous function) (require.js, line 626)
    each (require.js, line 57)
    breakCycle (require.js, line 613)
    (anonymous function) (require.js, line 626)
    each (require.js, line 57)
    breakCycle (require.js, line 613)
    (anonymous function) (require.js, line 626)
    each (require.js, line 57)
    breakCycle (require.js, line 613)
    (anonymous function) (require.js, line 626)
    each (require.js, line 57)
    breakCycle (require.js, line 613)
    (anonymous function) (require.js, line 700)
    each (require.js, line 57)
    checkLoaded (require.js, line 699)
    completeLoad (require.js, line 1576)
    onScriptLoad (require.js, line 1679)
```

The 'anonymous function it is referencing in line 12 of hf_postView.js is

```
template: _.template($('#listTpl').html()),
```

### --------------------------------------

SpecRunner.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>Jasmine Test Runner</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../test/jasmine/lib/jasmine.css">
</head>
<body>
```

SpecRunner.js - Partial!!

```
specs.push('spec/PostModelSpec');
specs.push('spec/PostCollectionSpec');
specs.push('spec/PostViewSpec');

require(['boot'], function(){
  require(specs, function(){
    window.onload();
  });
});
```

PostViewSpec.js

```
define(['views/base'], function(Base) {

  describe("View :: PostView", function() {
    it('View :: Should have tag name', function() {
      var base = new Base();
      base.render()
      expect(base.tagName).toEqual('div');
    });

  }); //describe
});//define
```

views/base.js

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'views/hf_appView', //****REMOVE this and the hfAppView below, and the test passes ******//
  'collections/hf_collections'], function($, _, Backbone, hfAppView, hfposts){

    return Base = Backbone.View.extend({
      el: '#securities',

      render: function() {
         //add code here
      }
    });

});
```

### --------------------------------------------------

PostViewSpec.js - Second Test Example - THIS DOESNT WORK AT ALL using a different view module.

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'views/hf_postView'], function($, _, Backbone, hfPostView) {

    it('View :: Should have tag name', function() {
      var base = new hfPostView();
      base.render()
      expect(base.tagName).toEqual('li');
    });

  }); //describe
});//define
```

views/hf_postView

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'models/hf_models',
  'views/hf_appView',
  'utils'], function($, _, Backbone, PostModel, hfAppView, utils){

    return hfPostView = Backbone.View.extend({
      tagName: 'li',
      className: 'securities',
      template: _.template($('#listTpl').html()),
      events: {
        'click .delete': 'deletePost'
      },

      initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'destroy', this.remove);
        if(!this.model) {
          throw new Error('Must have HFPOST model');
        }
      },

      render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(   
          this.model.toJSON()
        ));
        return this; 
      },

      deletePost: function() {
        var confirmed = confirm("Are you sure?");
        if (confirmed) {
          this.model.destroy();
          utils.showAlert('Entry was deleted', '', 'alert-warning');
        }
      } //delete post
    }); //Backbone View
});
```

### --------------------------------------------------

PostCollectionSpec.js - THIS works only if I remove the references to the hf_postView as well.

```
define(['collections/hf_collections', 'views/hf_postView'], function(hfposts, hfPostView) {

  describe('Controller :: Post Controller', function () {
    var posts;
    beforeEach(function() {
      posts = hfposts;
    });

    it('url should be /api', function() {
      expect(posts.url).toEqual('/api');
    });

    it('should create new model', function() {
      var post1 = hfposts.set({name: 'thisPost'});
      expect(post1.get("name")).toEqual('thisPost');
    });

  }); //describe
}); //define
```

Comment: Odd suggestion:  do you have Safari?  Try opening  the test runner in it.  The JS engine there should at least tell you what it was trying to evaluate when it deferenced the `undefined` value.  That may help track down where the trouble is.

Comment: Hey Peter.  Thanks for the suggestion.  I updated the question with the much improved error message.  More specifically, the error is: `[Warning] Invalid CSS property declaration at: * (jasmine.css, line 16)
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'n.replace')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will happen if you pass `_.template(...)` an empty DOM element.  With un-minified `underscore.js`, doing this ...

```
_.template($('#thisDoesNotExist'), { foo: "bar" });
```

... leads to ...

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null underscore.js:1304 _.template
```

Line 1304 of `underscore.js` is doing this:

```
text.replace(matcher, function(match, escape, interpolate, evaluate, offset) {
    source += text.slice(index, offset).replace(escaper, escapeChar);
    // ... and so on
```

Your error of attempting to evaluate `n.replace` is the minified version of that `text.replace(...)` call.

It happens because your unit test of the View is attempting to load something from the page that (I assume) is outside of the view itself via `$('#listTpl')`.  The DOM element with ID "listTpl" does not exist on the page that is hosting the unit tests, so it returns nothing.  Bummer.

How to fix it?  Since you're already using RequireJS, I suggest you also use [the text plugin](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#text).  This would allow you to define your template files wholly outside of the pages that are hosting the views in the application, which is darn nice for testing.  It's also really easy to get running in an existing RequireJS app, as there is no extra download or configuration; just use the `text!` prefix for the dependency you want.

Once you've moved your template out to a separate file, your View might look something like this:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'models/hf_models',
    'views/hf_appView',
    // Assume you created a separate directory for templates ...
    'text!templates/list.template',
    'utils'], function($, _, Backbone, PostModel, hfAppView, listTemplate, utils){

        return hfPostView = Backbone.View.extend({
            tagName: 'li',
            className: 'securities',
            // Woohoo!  The text plugin provides our template content!
            template: _.template(listTemplate),
            events: {
                'click .delete': 'deletePost'
            },
        // ... and so on ...
```

After that, your unit test does not have to change.  Just requiring in `views/hf_postView` will automatically bring in the template text & any other dependencies.

For good measure:  I'm a big fan of testing Backbone Views by asserting stuff as close to what the real application will see as possible.  Some of my View tests look like:

```
describe('after the View has rendered', function() {
    var view;

    beforeEach(function() {
        view = new MyView({
            model: mockModel
        });
        view.render();
    });

    it('initially has a "Submit" button', function() {
        var content = view.$el.html();
        var matched = content.indexOf('<button>Submit</button>');
        expect(match).to.be.greaterThan(-1);
    });
});
```

Not exactly that, but you get the idea.

Comment: This is absolute gold!  The Requirejs text plugin has improved my app immensely.  Once I used Karma to load the tpl's through a web server to avoid cross origin request errors, everything else fell into place.  Thank you again!